# Strange margin for buttons

Tags: css

I'm observing this strange margin between buttons that I can't figure out. See the screenshots
[image]
[image]

This is done with Chrome inspector. All the buttons are the same. As you can see, each one has a right-bottom margin, but no left margin. Which is why I can't understand **why there's a gap between the margin of button 2 and button 3**.

Tested on Chrome and Safari.

Here's the HTML code (the pagination buttons are in the `tfoot` of a `table`):

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
        <button class="small">&#60;</button>
        <button class="primary small">1</button>
        <button class="small">2</button>
        <button class="small">3</button>
        <button class="small">4</button>
        <button class="small">&#62;</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: Try removing all white-space like this: `</button><button>`, etc. Also see [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: Thanks for the link @ACJ, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Pick an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's white space between the button elements that is treated as a single space. Remove it by sticking the buttons together:

```
<button></button><button></button>
```

Or by adding HTML comments between them:

```
<button></button><!--
--><button></button>
```

Or if using PHP or such, add opening/closing tags between them to avoid the HTML space:

```
<button></button><?php
?><button></button>
```

Or by setting the font-size of the wrapper to 0 to avoid the space from having any width (then set the font-size on the buttons back to normal).

```
td {
  font-size: 0;
}
td button {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because HTML renders white-space between your buttons.

How to fix it:

1. Put wrapper `font-size: 0;` and buttons `font-size: 16px;`
2. Apply comments to your layout:

---

```
</button><!--
--><button>
```

3. Float buttons to left